# QDK file not found error in LiH Simulation

Tags: quantum-computing

I am on MacOS.  While "dotnet run" on unmodified version of "LithiumHydrideGUI" I am getting the following unhandled exception as

> File Not Found for
>   'Quantum-release-v0.3.1810/Chemistry/LithiumHydrideGUI/..\IntegralData\YAML\LiHData\integrals_lih_sto-3g_0.800.nw.out.yaml'.

I do see that the file is very much present in the directory one level up that is at "Chemistry" folder.  Please let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch the direction of the slashes from "\" to "/". You will find the line for this in the "Program" file.

Comment: Thanks very much, Nick.  Yes, realized the slashes had to be Mac consistent and changed them which worked (forgot to update here - sorry).